# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin iOS menu disabled

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I loaded Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Xamarin   4.0.3.214 (0dd817c)
Xamarin.Android   6.0.3.5 (a94a03b)
Xamarin.iOS   9.6.1.8 (3a25bf1)

However, when I bring up Visual Studio, the Tools/iOS menus items are disabled.  The Android menu items ARE enabled.

Comment: Why is this a bad question? It makes no sense that the options are disabled when no project is opened and all the stuff is installed. How can you connect a Mac if the menu options are disabled. Disabled without an explanation is a big UX mistake that all sofware still has.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed Xamarin on a Mac and paired it to your Windows machine

> Requirements & Installation
>
> There are a few requirements that must be adhered to when developing for iOS in Visual Studio. As briefly mentioned in the overview, a Mac is required to compile IPA files, and applications cannot be deployed to a device without Apple’s certificates and code-signing tools. Also, the iOS simulator can be used only on a Mac.

[Introduction to Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/)

Answer (score 1):

Patience is a virtue.  Eventually, the menu enabled itself while I was looking at a training video.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. When I installed Visual Studio 2017, first thing I did was to download an existing Xamarin project. When I checked the 'iOS' menu item in `Tools` it was all disabled.

After a restart of the system, I tried to create a new `Cross Platform App (Xamarin)`. Once the solution is created, I got the following message and the `iOS` menu has Mac Agent option enabled.

[image]